# Cut jpg file using imagemagick

Tags: c++, imagemagick, jpeg

I want to know if and how this is possible:

I want to make a function in C++ which will receive a JPEG file and coordinates from artoolkit marker and cut the JPEG using those coordinates in order to create a new smaller JPEG file.
Coding in Xcode

Answer (score 1):

I don't know imagemagic but there is the commandline [imagestack](http://code.google.com/p/imagestack/) tool which can crop images

`imagestack -load inputfilename.jpg -crop startx starty width height -save outputfilename.jpg`

If you can get the coordinates out of the other app you can write a script to pass them on the commandline to imagestack - details depends on your OS

Comment: thanks @Martin, i use MACOSX, and i thing the imagestack its only for win32 :( but thanks for the help